# Como agregar filas de un datagrid en otro?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un datagrid con datos que traigo con una consulta de la BD. Le puse una columna checkbox en la posición 0 y quiero que todas las columnas que seleccione se me pasen a otro datagrid cuando presione un botón. Como haría para pasar fila por fila al datagrid nuevo ? Probé hacer:

```
datagridNuevo.Rows.Add(datagridViejo.Rows[posicion]);
```

¡Pero no me funciona!

Edit:

Agrego imagen del error que me tira:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: Hola @JuanAndressolanas. ¿Te da algún error al intentar añadirla como has dicho? ¿Ambas tablas tienen exactamente los mismos campos? ¿La inserción la haces al señalar el checkbox o pulsas algún botón para comprobar todos los registros de la tabla y es ahí donde haces la inserción?

Comment: Hola, edito la pregunta y adjunto imagen de lo que me muestra!

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano te respondo todo. No se usar mucho los datagrid, el datagrid viejo no esta especificado que campos tiene, se autogenera con el select a la BD. Luego el datagrid nuevo le agregue 6 columnas(es la misma cantidad que tiene el datagrid viejo). Las columnas las agregue con dgv.columns.add("nombre","nombre")

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tratar de eliminar los elementos de un `ItemsSource`, y pasárselos al otro. Siguiendo el código de ejemplo de tu pregunta, esto te debería funcionar (no he probado el código, por lo que es posible que pueda contener algún erro, sin embargo creo que vale para ilustrar la respuesta.):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DummyContext.DummyContext context = (DummyContext.DummyContext)this.DataContext;

        for (int i=0; i < context.PrincipalDummySource.Count; i++)
        {
            if (context.PrincipalDummySource.ElementAt(i).MustPass )
            {
                context.AuxDummySource.Add(context.PrincipalDummySource.ElementAt(i));
                context.PrincipalDummySource.RemoveAt(i);
            }                
        }
    }
```